# attaching additional storage accounts with SAS key while creating HDInsight cluster from the Azure portal

Tags: azure-hdinsight

How do I specify an additional storage account with SAS keyfrom Azure portal while creating HDInsgith cluster? It's expecting actual storage key , not SAS key. Ideally I want to do that and export a template out of it. My goal is to get ARM template example for attaching storage with SAS key to HDInsight cluster. But I am not able to find this template anywhere. I just need an example that I can use.

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have option to attach additional storage accounts with SAS key while creating HDInsight cluster from the Azure portal.

[image]

I would request you to provide the feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.